# Google map javascript api unable to load markers from mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a bit of a problem with putting up markers from database i followed this guide https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3. The page just loads but with no markers, I have also checked if the xml generator was working and Yes it does. Could someone help me out what I'm doing wrong? here is my index file.

```
     <?php include('connection_db.php');?>
```

```
     downloadUrl("xmlspitter.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    shadow: icon.shadow
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
      }
      });
     function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
     });
   }
 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>   


 </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="contain">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Note: `xmlspitter.php` has correct output from my db. Also if anyone knows any more good tutorials please do tell me thanks.

//EDIT
This is the map from external js

```
    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
```

and `xmlspitter.php` if anyone was interested

```
   <?php  
    include('connection_db.php');

   // Start XML file, create parent node

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
  $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 



   // Select all the rows in the markers table

  $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   } 

     header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

   // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
   // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
   $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
   $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
   $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
   $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
   $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
   $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
   $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
 } 

 echo $dom->saveXML();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you have shown, your java script code is not being run. It should all be placed in the initialize function.

Also you haven't initialized the `customIcons` variable or given it values. If you are not using it, it can just be removed. It should just use the default marker then.

from guide

*Custom Icons
You can specify custom icons and shadows for your markers.
Start by creating an associative array which associates your icons to your type strings: 'restaurant' or 'bar.' This makes the icons easy to reference later when you create markers from the XML.*

```
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};
```

I actually did something similar last year. Though I used php to populate the markers out of the database and not javascript and xml.

Edited: The blog link is no longer valid.

Comment: Sorry to mention. I have it in a separate file. Also it shows, but the markers and showing up. xml also works.

Comment: Another javascript file? Is the variable in proper scope? can this script access the variable?

Comment: i posted the sourecode yep the script can access the external js file

Comment: You reference the customIcons variable but it's never defined or given values.

Comment: In the example the loading of the markers is part of the load function.

Comment: What if i delete the custom icons? it should show default markers right? I primarily removed them.

Comment: Also what/how to put the values in those custom markers i can't find them in the guide.

Comment: Found the error the tutorial has an error a misplaced "}". but when you said "From what you have shown, your java script code is not being run. It should all be placed in the initialize function." i figured it out thanks.